# DOM Crawler and The current node list is empty - how to get list

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

I need help with DOM Crawler in Symfony 3.2.
Here is my code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.wakacje.pl/wczasy/peru/');
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$crawler = $crawler->filter('#gridWithPagination > div > div')->each(function (Crawler $node) {
    return $node->filter('div.desc > a');
});

foreach ($crawler as $item) {
    var_dump($item->attr('href'));
}
```

As you can see, I want to get the URI parameter from all occurrences on the list, but this code is returning only the first instance, and also an error:

> The current node list is empty

What I've missed?
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you needed to filter twice, but a more straightforward CSS selector  seems to work for me:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.wakacje.pl/wczasy/peru/');
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$nodes = $crawler->filter('div#gridWithPagination div.desc a');

$nodes->each(function ($item) {
    echo $item->attr('href').'<br>';
});
```